# Execution times when executing v.net.steiner is too high

Tags: grass-gis

I have a question related to execution times when running v.net.steiner.
When I try to connect 200 points by running v.net.steiner, it doesn't take more than 2 - 5 minutes. However, when I try to connect 2000 points, execution time rises up to 10-15 hours, is there any alternative way to decrease these times?

I am using Windows 10, I have 16 GB of memory, Intel Core i7 vPro. GRASS version is 7.8.2, and executing the code from the Python console of QGIS with the following code:

```
# Compute steiner(v.net.steiner)
alg_params = {
    '-g' : False, 
    'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 
    'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 
    'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 
    'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 
    'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 
    'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 
    'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 
    'acolumn' : '', 
    'arc_type' : [0,1], 
    'input' : outputs['ExplodeLines']['OUTPUT'], 
    'npoints' : -1,
    'output' : pSteiner_temp,
    'points' : lRAhouses,
    'terminal_cats' : '1-100000',
    'threshold' : 50 
}
```

Find attached a picture of the Steiner I am trying to compute. In this particular case, I am trying to connect 4252 points, since this number is by far too high, I've divided the set of points in 4 sets of ~1000 points each one, but even though the running time is too high, is there any alternative way to shorter the execution time?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please choose your most pressing issue and update the Question to focus on that. Please be sure to specify the exact operating system and GRASS release in use. I'd recommend going through a full question&answer process before asking the other questions in new Questions.

Comment: How many points are in the lRAhouses layer? I would note (from the v.net.steiner manual page) that:  "Note that 'Minimum Steiner Tree' problem is NP-hard..."

Comment: As you can see from the picture, there are 4.252 points. Yes, it is a NP-hard problem, the v.net.steiner version of GRASS is based on a heuristic algorithm that it is not very efficient, as the author states in the manual. This is the reason why I am asking the question

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend  to write your Steiner tree problems to a text file and use an external software. The fastest software
is this one:
https://scipjack.zib.de/

It will likely solve your problems in less than a second, runs also on Windows and is open-source (be warned that I am one of the developers, so I might not be completely  unbiased)